# How to do conditional decorator

Tags: python-3.x, decorator

```
def decorators(*args, **kwargs): 
    def inner(func): 
        print ("Inner()")
        return func

    def err(func):
        print ("Your input wrong")

    if kwargs['test']== "test1":
        print("decorators()")
        return inner
    else:
        return err

@decorators(test="test1") 
def funcdemo1():
    print ("funcdemo1()")
def demo():
    print ("demo() call")
funcdemo1()
demo()
```

The above code if I pass `test="test2"` in the decorators then the funcdemo1() stop the execution and show some error mesage, and the demo() will be execute.

**Is it possible?**

Comment: What exactly is your question? Nothing is impossible...

Comment: If I pass ```@decorators(test="test1")``` then the the output is

```{'test': 'test1'}

decorators()

Inner()

funcdemo1()

demo() call```


But Now I want If I pass

 ```@decorators(test="test2")```

then the output I want
```{'test': 'test11'}

Your input wrong

demo() call```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you decorate `funcdemo1` and then call it, *something* is going to get called.  In the `err` case, to avoid the effect of `funcdemo1` getting called and to avoid the script blowing up, you need to provide a function that does nothing:

```
    def nada():
        return

    def err(func):
        print ("Your input wrong")
        return nada
```

Comment: But when the ```err``` call, then ```funcdemo1()``` is execute. But I want if the ```err``` call then ```funcdemo1()``` will not execute. Only execute the ```demo()```

Comment: Sorry I missed that.  I have fixed my answer.